# Python Move Files Based On Name

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, move

To give credit, the code I am currently working with is from this response by **cji**, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446857/how-to-match-and-move-files-into-corresponding-folders-using-python)

I am trying to recursively pull all files from the source folder, and move them into folders from the file names first-five characters `0:5`

My Code Below:

```
import os
import shutil

srcpath = "SOURCE"
srcfiles = os.listdir(srcpath)

destpath = "DESTINATION"

# extract the three letters from filenames and filter out duplicates
destdirs = list(set([filename[0:5] for filename in srcfiles]))


def create(dirname, destpath):
    full_path = os.path.join(destpath, dirname)
    os.mkdir(full_path)
    return full_path

def move(filename, dirpath):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(srcpath, filename)
                ,dirpath)

# create destination directories and store their names along with full paths
targets = [(folder, create(folder, destpath)) for folder in destdirs]

for dirname, full_path in targets:
    for filename in srcfiles:
        if dirname == filename[0:5]:
            move(filename, full_path)
```

Now, changing `srcfiles = os.listdir(srcpath)` and `destdirs = list(set([filename[0:5] for filename in srcfiles]))` **with the code below** gets me the paths in one variable and the first five characters of the file names in another.

```
srcfiles = []
destdirs = []

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(srcpath):
    for file in files:
       srcfiles.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    for name in files:
       destdirs.append(list(set([name[0:5] for file in srcfiles])))
```

How would I go about modifying the original code to use this... Or if someone has a better idea on how I would go about doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't really test it very easily, but I think this code should work:

```
import os
import shutil

srcpath = "SOURCE"
destpath = "DESTINATION"

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(srcpath):
    for file in files:
        subFolder = os.path.join(destpath, file[:5])
        if not os.path.isdir(subFolder):
            os.makedirs(subFolder)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), subFolder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! 'os.path.mkdir(subFolder):' did not work for me. I had to remove the path. Using: 'os.makedirs(subFolder)'

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my answer. The `mkdir` and `makedirs` functions are in the `os` module, not the `os.path` submodule. `mkdir` should work, unless the subfolders are nested more than one level.

Comment: if I, say in the future, wanted to elaborate with the sub folders... would that be an easy customization? So Say I had a file called 045679.jpg, I would want it to drop into a 0 Folder > 045 Folder > 04567 Folder or something.

Comment: Yes, you could just do this: `subFolder = os.path.join(destpath, file[:3], file[:5])`, and the `os.makedirs()` function would create all the folders necessary.

Comment: Its funny, right after posting the question, I thought to myself, why not try adding 'file[],' myself. Thanks for all the help!