# Move files on respective folder based on first char (Python)

Tags: python, shutil

I have this folder structure:

[image: folder_tree]

In `mixed` folder there are various file which have, as first char of the name, a digit from 0 to 9. What I want to do is to move all files which begins with 0 to the 0 folder, all which begin with 1 to 1 folder and so on..

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090884/python-move-files-based-on-name) solution but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `os` module.

```
import os
path = <path_of_main_folder>
for file in os.listdir(path + '\\mixed'):
    full_path = path + '\\mixed\\' + file
    os.rename(full_path, path + '\\' + file[0] + '\\' + file) #move from mixed to folder w/ same first char
```

Comment: my bad it should be `os.rename()` i got my names wrong

Comment: With `os.move` it says `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'move'`

Comment: @Link i fixed it it should be `rename()` :)